# Which event is raised on the client side when the drop down list initially gets loaded?

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, drop-down-menu, web

I have a drop down list as below:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAuthenticationMode" DataMember="AuthenticationMode" runat="server"
                                    CssClass="ddlAuthenticationMode" AppendDataBoundItems="true" onchange="onSelectedIndexChange(this.value);">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Windows Authentication" Selected="True" Value="Windows"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="SQL Server Authentication" Value="SqlServer"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Which event is raised on the client side when the drop down list initially gets loaded?

I added the below code to handle the load event but it never raised:

```
$('.ddlAuthenticationMode').load(function (){

                alert('loaded');          
            });
```

thanks,

Comment: @sll your comment is not helpful :p

Answer (score 2):

There is no client side event that gets raised when the dropdown is initially loaded. It is part of the DOM that gets sent to the client from the server. You could subscribe to the [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event in order to ensure that you can manipulate it on the client.